# Mongoose only saves certain fields (Mongoose + Restify)

Tags: mongodb, coffeescript, mongoose, restify

This code won't save to my MongoDB. If I change doc.foursqure_key to doc.username or doc.password, it saves just fine.

```
@User.findOne({ username: 'justin' }, (err, doc) =>
        doc.foursquare_key = "your mom"
        doc.save()
```

My User schema:
    {username, password, foursquare_key}

Been staring for 2 days... driving me crazy. I don't understand why I can't save this one field, but the others are fine! Any help is amazing!

Comment: It would help if you showed your actual schema definition code.

Comment: any errors happening?

Comment: @JohnnyHK - You just solved my problem. That's what I get for working through the middle of the night! This field was missing from the Schema! (insert embarrassed smiley here)

Comment: Not sure that it's a restify question...